# how to disable/enable dropdown angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

How can I enable/disable a dropdown based on the selection of another dropdown menu?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="abc">
    <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let data of datay" 
            [ngValue]="data.code" 
            [attr.disabled]="true"> 
        {{data.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Any sample code is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, just to get it clear, are you trying to disable another dropdown based on the value you have selected on your current dropdown?

Comment: @wentjun , yeah

Comment: @Developer, you can use [attr.disabled]  like `[attrib.disabled]="condition?true:null"` where condition is a contidion that you want. if you use `[attr.disabled]="false"` not work, you must use "null" to not render the attribute

Answer (score 2):

Here is example with reactive forms as answer with template-driven forms is already posted:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select name="field1" formControlName="field1">
    <option *ngFor="let value of [1, 2, 3]" [value]="value">{{value}}</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select name="field1" formControlName="field2">
    <option *ngFor="let value of [1, 2, 3]" [value]="value">{{value}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

TS:

```
  form;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      field1: new FormControl(),
      field2: new FormControl()
    });

    this.form.controls.field1.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      value === '2' ? this.form.controls.field2.disable() : this.form.controls.field2.enable();
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm using form builder and tried this :  this.form.fb.field1.value.subscribe(value=>{
      value === 'ABC' ? this.form.controls.field2.disable() : this.form.controls.field2.enable();
    }); is this the right  way to do ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if the dropdown is connected to a FormGroup.

If yes, simply disable the FormControl with `formGroup.get('yourPath').disable({onlySelf: true});`

If not, you can also just use the `[disabled]="isFieldDisabled"` property on the `<select>` property.

If you use a FormGroup with your DropDownField but choose to disable the DropDownField via `[disabled]="..."`, then you will get much yellow text in your console.

Comment: This answer worked for me. IonicMan is also correct with his last sentence - in Chrome if the Default levels dropdown in the Console area is set to show warnings, you will see a lot of yellow text (i.e. warnings) about the recommended approach for setting the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by using 2-way data binding. First, we bind the first `<select>` element to `data1`. This will contain the value `data.code` of the selected option from the first  element.

Let's assume that we will disable the second `<select>` element if the user selects the option with the `data.code` value of '1'.

Then, on our second `<select>` element, we bind the `disabled` attribute to the condition, such that the `disabled` arribute will be true when `data1 === '1'`.

```
<select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="data1" id="dropdown1">
  <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let data of datay" [ngValue]="data.code"> 
    {{data.name}} 
  </option>
</select>

<select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="data2" [disabled]="data1==='1'">
  <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let data of datay2" [ngValue]="data.code"> 
    {{data.name}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: <select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="data1" id="dropdown1">
  <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let data of datay" [ngValue]="data.code"> 
    {{data.name}} 
  </option>
</select>

<select class="custom-select" [(ngModel)]="data2" [disabled]="data1==='1'">
                                    <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
                                    <option value="test"></option>
                                    <option value="test2"></option>
                                </select>

Comment: it is string value.

Comment: @Developer can you look at this demo(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkxeei?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that I have made instead? I am pretty sure it works :) the second select will be disabled if you select 1 on your first select

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  selectedFruit = null;
  fruits = [
    { name: 'Apple', code: 'Apple' },
    { name: 'Mango', code: 'Mango' },
    { name: 'Orange', code: 'Orange' },
    { name: 'Grapes', code: 'Grapes' },
    { name: 'Peach', code: 'Peach' },
  ];

  models = [
    { name: 'iPhone XS Max', code: 'iPhone XS Max' },
    { name: 'iPhone XS', code: 'iPhone XS' },
    { name: 'iPhone X', code: 'iPhone X' },
    { name: 'iPhone 8 Plus', code: 'iPhone 8 Plus' },
    { name: 'iPhone 8', code: 'iPhone 8' },
  ]
}
```

And in your template:

```
<h2>Fruits</h2>
<select class="custom-select" id="abc" [(ngModel)]="selectedFruit">
  <option value="null" hidden>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [ngValue]="fruit.code"> {{fruit.name}}</option>
</select>

<h2>Phone Models</h2>
<select class="custom-select" id="abc" [disabled]="selectedFruit !== 'Apple'">
  <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let model of models" [ngValue]="model.code"> {{model.name}}</option>
</select>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msddsc) for your ref.